Проблемы с подключением JS модуля (MIME type error)
Пытался подключить скрипт к странице в котором имортирую библеотеку, но получил следующее:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Использовал Live Server и OpenServer
Вот импорт и подключение скрипта:
<script src="scripts/script.js" type="module"></script> 
--------------------------------------------------------
import math from '/node_modules/mathjs';


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка

А если прямо браузером открыть страницу scripts/script.js, то что скажет? Может там ругается на что-то - доступа нет, например. Или путь неправильный.

Стоит отметить, что при отправке модулей js нам надо устанавливать mime-тип отправляемого контента в "text/javascript" https://metanit.com/web/javascript/19.1.php

Спасибо всем, последний коммент помог разобраьться с проблемой
